# Detect WebSocket connection closed

Tags: android, node.js, websocket

I'm using node.js and [WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node) to build a simple chat websocket server.

The client is an Android app.

The server have to communicate with the clients in two way:

- websocket message when the client is connected (app open in foreground)
- Push notification using Google GCM else

But there is a little problem that i need to figure out..

When the client is connected to the server and the internet connection drops, the server is not notified about that because the client did not send the closing frame.. So for like 10 seconds, the server thinks that the connection is still alive.

If in those 10 seconds the server send the message over the socket.. the message can never reach the client.

I need to detect when the connection is closed, or another way to send the message using GCM when the connection it's closed.

Is there a way?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#user-content-how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections Use ping/ping messages to check if the connection is alive.

Answer (score 1):

From the side of the server an unclean disconnect (no disconnect messages sent) is indistinguishable from a very slow connection.

What you need to do is have some sort of heartbeat. WebSockets has pings on the protocol level for this. If your library exposes this, then set the ping to a delay you are willing to accept, and add a handler for when this fails/doesn't complete after a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I can't ping the device every second to check the connection, it will drain the battery.

Comment: Unfortunately, without any data being transmitted it's just not possible to detect a disconnect.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, because: It is not possibile, and I have found another better way to handle ***my specific case***.

- When the server send a message to the client, the client reply to the server, to let the server know that the message has been delivered to the client.
- If the server do not receive the response from the client after a timeout, the connection is considered closed.
- Proceed to send the message over GCM (or store it to be sent again when the client reconnect).